# UIPageControl , white dot does not get highlighted

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uipagecontrol

Hey guys , I am using the UIPagecontrol with a scrollview. It works well , but there is this one scenario the white does not get highlighted. It happens after we go to a another view from the scrollview and then comes back and reload data. The white does not appear but the number of pages appear correctly. But it gets highlighted ,if I swipe the scrollview.

I have correctly set the number of pages and current page correctly. I am doing this from the main thread. Furthermore, I have tried to update the page control using a timer and I've tried updateCurrentPageDisplay. But no luck.

So any suggestions ? ...

Comment: If youre setting your current page in viewDidLoad try doing it in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear. viewDidLoad does not get called when coming back from a vc in a navigation controller

Answer (score 4):

[Erratic UIPageControls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115355/erratic-uipagecontrols) - see the answer to this question, it fixed my problem. I was calling [pageControl setNumberOfPages: 0]. You should never call this, so I changed it to [pageControl setNumberOfPages: 1]. I was just trying to reset my controls.